# How to style a select widget in tcomb-form-native

Tags: react-native, select, styles, tcomb-form-native

I am able to style the **options** portion of the select widget -- the bottom portion of the widget.  But I don't know how to style the top portion of the select widget -- the part that resembles a textbox.  How would I set a white background color for the top element of the "Brand" select in the screenshot.

[image: how to style the textbox portion of a select widget]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
t.Form.stylesheet.pickerContainer.normal.backgroundColor = '#fff';
```